Website with SSL running on Ubuntu with Apache which serve Mattermost, give "Server Not Found" error after using Mattermost App on desktop
After installing Ubuntu Mattermost, the application gives the error "address not found" shortly after using Mattermost App on Desktop.
Notes:

SSL is installed for sub.domain.com and domain.com.
When the application is used for a short time, sometimes both domains, sometimes only the mattermost.domain.com gives this error.
SSL certificates are installed by certbot (letsencrypt).

config files:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mattermost.domain.com
    ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/users/websocket [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]

    <Location /api/v3/users/websocket>
        Require all granted
        ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v3/users/websocket
        ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8065/api/v3/users/websocket
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.domain.com
    </Location>

    <Location />
        Require all granted
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.domain.com
    </Location>

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mattermost.domain.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mattermost.domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mattermost.domain.com
  ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.domain.com
  </Location>


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

I tried to install Mattermost server on an apache server. "https" does not work suddenly.
